# How do I compute values inside an array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array of javascript objects, and I want to create a key:value pair that is the product of two values.

I can solve this using much longer code outside of the object (i.e. in a 'for each' loop), but I thought there must be an easier way. Perhaps you could point me to the right direction?

```
let DB = [
    {
      number: 100,
      factor: 1.5
      product: this.number * this.factor // doesn't work :(
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ];
```

I want product to equal 150, which is 100 * 1.5, but I don't know how to get access to those 2 values.

Comment: `let DB = [
    {
      number: 100,
      factor: 1.5
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ].map(
    o => ({ ...o, product: o.number * o.factor })
);`

Comment: All the objects have properties `number` and `factor` and you want to add a new one callled `product` as described (`= number * factor`)?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts haha snap

Comment: For a reference: [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), but I suggest exploring the other array methods in the left navigation bar - there's lots of useful stuff there.

Answer (score 1):

you cant do it inside the array, but its easy enough to solve using map.

```
[ { number: 100, factor: 1.5}].map(element => ({...element, product: element.number * element.factor}));
```

`.map()` goes through the array and makes a new one with each element being the result of the function passed in.

The `...` is spread, it takes all of the properties in the original object and puts them onto the new object you are making.

Answer (score 0):

or simply: (because map method creates a new array, otherwise use forEach method)

```js
let DB = [ { number: 100, factor: 1.5 }
         , { number: 100, factor: 1.2 }
         ];

for (let db of DB ) { db.product = db.number * db.factor }


/// verify =
for (let db of DB ) console.log( JSON.stringify(db))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do the calculation inside the object, you can try using a getter as documented here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

```js
x = { 
  number: 100, 
  factor: 1.5, 
  get product() { return this.number * this.factor} 
 }
 
console.log(x.product)
```